# как сделать, чтобы при закрытии окна готовой exe программы на Python c использованием eel при создании GUI убить процесс консольный? остаётся висеть

Tags: python, многопоточность, gui, pyinstaller, eel

Сама суть вопроса в заголовке, добавлю только что консоль при создании через pyinstaller я скрыл(если это имеет значение)

Но впоследствии в процессах в диспетчере задач после закрытия окна программа остаётся висеть..

Как прописать в коде, чтобы при закрытии Gui окна, закрывался весь процесс программы?

Библиотеки используемые в коде:

```
import pyautogui as pg
import keyboard, eel, time
from threading import Thread
```

в процессе работы открываются потоки, есть предположение, что они остаются висеть после закрытия окна..
если да, то как сделать, чтобы при закрытии Windows окна программы они полностью закрывались?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

необходимо в потоках указывать `daemon=True`.

пример:

```
potok=Thread(target=f1,daemon=True)
```